# Image in docker-compose with arguments

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have docker's image which I run with this command:

```
docker run -it -v $PWD:/app -v /media/******/:/media/******:ro -e
"ES_URL=http://******:9200/" -e "DATA_DIR=/media/*******/" ******/pyscraper-with-proxy
/bin/bash
```

As you can see, I have few flags that I need to include. I want to run this image from docker-compose, but I don't know how to set this arguments from yml file.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two ways for environment variables:

Via ENVIRONMENT: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#environment

```
environment:
  ES_URL: http://******:9200/
  DATA_DIR: /media/*******/
```

Or via .env file: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#env-file

And for your volumes: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#volumes-volume-driver

```
volumes:
  # Specify an absolute path mapping
  - /opt/data:/var/lib/mysql
```

Comment: Okay, that's two of them. And I guess that -v arguments should go under "volumes" section?

Comment: Oh yeah sorry, I though you were only looking for ways to add environment variables to docker-compose. You're right about the volume section